# python blackjack ace problem which breaks my code

Tags: python

I currently am making a blackjack python minigame, where a player plays until he gets a blackjack or stands and returns the value of his deck. This game does not play against a dealer and instead just uses his hands as a score. My problem is, I cannot figure out a way to make aces go from 11 to 1 without looping and breaking the program. Here is my code:

```
   import random


def play():
    output = "Your hand: "
    player = []
    total=0
    count = 0
    while len(player) != 2:
        card = random.randint(1,52)
        if card <= 4:
            output += "A "
            total += 11
            player.append("A")
        elif card <= 8:
            output+="2 "
            total+=2
            player.append("2")
        elif card <= 12:
            output+="3 "
            total+=3
            player.append("3")
        elif card <= 16:
            output+="4 "
            total+=4
            player.append("4")
        elif card <= 20:
            output+="5 "
            total+=5
            player.append("5")
        elif card <= 24:
            output+="6 "
            total+=6
            player.append("6")
        elif card <= 28:
            output+="7 "
            total+=7
            player.append("7")
        elif card <= 32:
            output+="8 "
            total+=8
            player.append("8")
        elif card <= 36:
            output+="9 "
            total+=9
            player.append("9")
        elif card <= 40:
            output+="10 "
            total+=10
            player.append("10")
        elif card <= 44:
            output+="J "
            total+=10
            player.append("J")
        elif card <= 48:
            output+="Q "
            total+=10
            player.append("Q")
        elif card <= 52:
            output+= "K "
            total+=10
            player.append("K")
        if len(player) == 2:
            print(f"{output} ({total}) ")

    while len(player) >= 2:
        action_taken = input("Would you like to 'hit' or 'stand': ")
        if action_taken == "hit":
            card = random.randint(1,52)
            if card <= 4:
                output += "A "
                total += 11
                player.append("A")
            elif card <= 8:
                output+="2 "
                total+=2
                player.append("2")
            elif card <= 12:
                output+="3 "
                total+=3
                player.append("3")
            elif card <= 16:
                output+="4 "
                total+=4
                player.append("4")
            elif card <= 20:
                output+="5 "
                total+=5
                player.append("5")
            elif card <= 24:
                output+="6 "
                total+=6
                player.append("6")
            elif card <= 28:
                output+="7 "
                total+=7
                player.append("7")
            elif card <= 32:
                output+="8 "
                total+=8
                player.append("8")
            elif card <= 36:
                output+="9 "
                total+=9
                player.append("9")
            elif card <= 40:
                output+="10 "
                total+=10
                player.append("10")
            elif card <= 44:
                output+="J "
                total+=10
                player.append("J")
            elif card <= 48:
                output+="Q "
                total+=10
                player.append("Q")
            elif card <= 52:
                output+= "K "
                total+=10
                player.append("K")
            if len(player) >= 2 and total <=21:
                print(f"{output} ({total}) ")

        if total > 21:

            if "A" in player: #Ask why ace always messes up
                if count < 1:
                    count +=1
                    total-=10
                    print(f"{output} ({total}) ")
                if player.count("A") > 1:
                    total -= 10
                    print(f"{output} ({total}) ")
            else:
                print(f"{output} ({total}) ")
                print("BUST!")
                return total

        if action_taken == "stand":
            return total

        if action_taken != "hit" or "stand":
            print("Enter a valid input ('hit' or 'stand') ")


play()
```

Comment: What are the problematic symptoms when you get aces dealt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if "A" in player` will always be `True` once there's an ace in the deck, and so you never get to the `else` where you print "BUST!" and return, so the loop just continues. You can do something like incremeting `count` for every ace in the deck and then change the ace part to be:

```
    if total > 21:
        player_aces = player.count("A")  # How many aces the player has
        if player_aces != count: # Meaning there are aces that weren't checked
            for _ in range(player_aces - count):
                total -= 10  # Could also be simplified to: total -= 10 * (player_aces - count)
            count = player_aces
            print(f"{output} ({total}) ")
        else:
            print(f"{output} ({total}) ")
            print("BUST!")
            return total
```

Also, `if action_taken != "hit" or "stand"` doesn't check that `action_taken` is not "hit" and not "stand". An `or` treats both its inputs as `bool` values and returns whether at least one is `True`. The `!=` operator has precedence over `or`, so the line is actually `if (action_taken != "hit") or "stand"`. The left part of that does what it's supposed to do, but then the right part evaluates "stand" as a `bool`, and in python every non-empty string is evaluated as `True`. So the right expression is always `True`, and so is the `or` - and the program will always enter the `if` statement.

You probably want: `if action_taken != "hit" and action_taken != "stand"`.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by it checks stand and it not being an empty string? I am not quite sure I understand.

Answer (score 2):

There were a coupe of issues that I have fixed. I have created a counter for the number of Aces, this allows us to count how many times we can reduced the total by - otherwise we just keep removing 10.

Also the indentation of the last else statement needed moving out.

```
import random


def play():
    output = "Your hand: "
    player = []
    total=0
    count = 0
    reducedA = 0
    while len(player) != 2:
        card = 1
        #card = random.randint(1,52)
        if card <= 4:
            output += "A "
            total += 11
            reducedA+=1
            player.append("A")
        elif card <= 8:
            output+="2 "
            total+=2
            player.append("2")
        elif card <= 12:
            output+="3 "
            total+=3
            player.append("3")
        elif card <= 16:
            output+="4 "
            total+=4
            player.append("4")
        elif card <= 20:
            output+="5 "
            total+=5
            player.append("5")
        elif card <= 24:
            output+="6 "
            total+=6
            player.append("6")
        elif card <= 28:
            output+="7 "
            total+=7
            player.append("7")
        elif card <= 32:
            output+="8 "
            total+=8
            player.append("8")
        elif card <= 36:
            output+="9 "
            total+=9
            player.append("9")
        elif card <= 40:
            output+="10 "
            total+=10
            player.append("10")
        elif card <= 44:
            output+="J "
            total+=10
            player.append("J")
        elif card <= 48:
            output+="Q "
            total+=10
            player.append("Q")
        elif card <= 52:
            output+= "K "
            total+=10
            player.append("K")
        if len(player) == 2:
            print(f"{output} ({total}) ")

    while len(player) >= 2:
        action_taken = input("Would you like to 'hit' or 'stand': ")
        if action_taken == "hit":
            card = random.randint(1,52)
            if card <= 4:
                output += "A "
                total += 11
                player.append("A")
                reducedA += 1
            elif card <= 8:
                output+="2 "
                total+=2
                player.append("2")
            elif card <= 12:
                output+="3 "
                total+=3
                player.append("3")
            elif card <= 16:
                output+="4 "
                total+=4
                player.append("4")
            elif card <= 20:
                output+="5 "
                total+=5
                player.append("5")
            elif card <= 24:
                output+="6 "
                total+=6
                player.append("6")
            elif card <= 28:
                output+="7 "
                total+=7
                player.append("7")
            elif card <= 32:
                output+="8 "
                total+=8
                player.append("8")
            elif card <= 36:
                output+="9 "
                total+=9
                player.append("9")
            elif card <= 40:
                output+="10 "
                total+=10
                player.append("10")
            elif card <= 44:
                output+="J "
                total+=10
                player.append("J")
            elif card <= 48:
                output+="Q "
                total+=10
                player.append("Q")
            elif card <= 52:
                output+= "K "
                total+=10
                player.append("K")
            if len(player) >= 2 and total <=21:
                print(f"{output} ({total}) ")

        if total > 21:

            if "A" in player: #Ask why ace always messes up
                if count < 1:
                    count +=1
                    total-=10
                    print(f"{output} ({total}) ")
                if player.count("A") > 1 and reducedA:
                    total -= 10
                    reducedA -= 1
                    print(f"{output} ({total}) ")
                else:
                    print(f"{output} ({total}) ")
                    print("BUST!")
                    return total
            else:
                print(f"{output} ({total}) ")
                print("BUST!")
                return total

        if action_taken == "stand":
            return total

        if action_taken != "hit" or action_taken != "stand":
            print("Enter a valid input ('hit' or 'stand') ")


play()
```